# error on tags table in spec but it is in database on a schema load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I get the following error in a spec but the table is in dev and is in schema.rb:

```
1) ApiController task015: submit a value
   Failure/Error: seed_tags
   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
     Mysql2::Error: Table 'test_db.tags' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `tags`
   # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:139:in `block in seed_tags'
```

If I run:

```
Mon Sep 23$ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load
```

and then check:

```
show tables;
| tags
```

What is the next logical step to figure out what is going on?

thx

Comment: Hello, I can't provide any certain answer, but in your place, the first thing I would check is my spec_helper.rb or test_helper.rb to see if rails env is not forced to something else than "test".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with rake's use of the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable or how environment variable assignment can be combined with command execution in a single line, but on my system:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load
```

operates on the "dev" database and has no impact on the test database.

The way I've been instructed to initialize the test database with rake is with:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```